# How to implement paypal CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile

Tags: php, paypal

In my website we need to integrate paypal Recurring(CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile)
but we do not want to take credit card details in our end, we need to redirect user to paypal site and they will use paypal portal to fill credit card info and after that CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile will created...
How can I implement that?

Comment: Did you search on SO for 'CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile'?

Answer (score 2):

To start using recurring payments, where PayPal takes all the card details, you would use Express Checkout Recurring Payments.

To use this, call the following API calls, with (at least) the following parameters:

**`SetExpressCheckout`:**

```
$nvps = array();
$nvps["VERSION"] = "80.0";

$nvps["METHOD"] = "SetExpressCheckout";

$nvps["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION"] = "Sale";
$nvps["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"] = "1.00";
$nvps["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE"] = "GBP";
$nvps["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT"] = "1.00";

$nvps["L_BILLINGTYPE0"] = 'RecurringPayments';
$nvps["L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0"] = "the subscription";

$nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0"] = 1;
$nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0"]= "subscription";
$nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0"]= 1.00;
$nvps["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0"]= 1;
```

And **`CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`** with:

```
$nvps["PROFILESTARTDATE"] = "2011-07-08T17:40:00Z";
$nvps["BILLINGPERIOD"] = "Month";
$nvps["BILLINGFREQUENCY"] = "1";
$nvps["AMT"] = "1.00";
$nvps["CURRENCYCODE"] = "GBP";
$nvps["DESC"] = "the subscription";
```

Comment: Be careful when calling both SetExpressCheckout and CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile. This use case is ok, but to make it easier you may prefer using only one call to CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile including a INITAMT value.Do NOT use both CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile with an INITAMT and SetExpressCheckout, otherwise the payment will be done twice.

Comment: Note: the above applies only if you're specifying an AMT in your SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckoutPayment. DoExpressCheckoutPayment is an immediate payment, whereas INITAMT is batched and may be charged at some point in the next 24 hours.